# changing URL from array using jquery in previous/next gallery

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have a very simple previous/next photo gallery where I also want to change the URL for each photo which is a lightbox link to a larger image.

```
var img = [
  "images/railing.jpg",
  "images/stairwell.jpg",
  "images/sunset_railing.jpg",
  "images/sunset_house.jpg"
];

img.current = 0;
function showImage(i) {
  $("#imag").fadeOut( function() {
    this.src = img[img.current];
    $(this).fadeIn();
  });
}

function NextImage() {
  img.current = (img.current+1) % img.length;
  showImage(img.current);
}

function PreviousImage() {
  if (--img.current < 0)
    img.current = img.length - 1;
  showImage(img.current);
}

onload = function() {
  showImage(0);
};
```

This is called on the page with buttons using the NextImage and PreviousImage functions and it changes the image beautifully:

```
<a href="images/railing_detail.jpg" rel="lightbox">
  <img src="images/railing.jpg" alt="railing" name="BlackImage" 
       border="0" id="imag" />
</a>
```

I also want to be able change the href value of the link at the same time and can't get my head around the best way to go about this.

Comment: And I also want peace in the whole world. What have you tried to solve your problem? Have you read through official jquery documentation and numerous guides?

Comment: If the `href` is the same as the `src`, just use `$(this).closest('a').attr('href', img[img.current]);` inside the `showImage` function.

Comment: I have tried using split() to create my href which works but am having trouble integrating it into my showImage function without breaking it.
`fileName = img[img.current].split(/'.'/);`
`$("#lnk").attr("href", fileName[0] + "_detail.jpg");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a map of the img array as in using { } notation instead of [ ], e.g

```
var img = {
  "images/railing.jpg" : "link",
  "images/stairwell.jpg" : "link",
  .. etc
};
```

Reply to your first comment, if the img+link have to be assigned to an index, you can try

```
var img = [
  {"images/railing.jpg" : "link"},
  {"images/stairwell.jpg" : "link"},
  .. etc
];
```

or

```
var img = [
  ["images/railing.jpg","link"],
  ["images/stairwell.jpg", "link"],
  .. etc
];
```

`img[0][0]` is `"images/railing.jpg"`, `img[0][1]` is the link to `"images/railing.jpg"`

Use what you like

Comment: How would I call the [0] and [1] elements of the array within my original code?

Comment: Thank you dbf. I used your last option and called the variables in my function as `this.src = img[img.current][0];` and `$("#lnk").attr("href", img[img.current][1]);` ... works great!